# Save only schema from Microsoft SQL Server to a .SQL file using node and express

Tags: sql-server, schema

I want to connect to Microsoft SQL Server; the username, password, hostname etc are provided from a front end, and if the connection is successful with those values, then I want to save table schema (not data) as a `.SQL` file.

Please anyone help, how to proceed with it?

Comment: What is "I" in "I want to save table schema"? You have not provided any context but it sounds like you are writing code in some undefined language to run on some platform to do what SSMS does - generate scripts for tables (or more generally - database objects). Perhaps you should investigate [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem to me. https://xyproblem.info/